# Create multiple generations of children process

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork

So I'm trying to understand the concept of grandchildren.
I'm able to create a given number of sons (i.e brothers) but I don't know how to create multiple generations .
This is what I did to create one grandson :

```
int main ()
{
//Displaying the father
printf("Initial : Father = %d\n\n", getpid()); 

/****** FORK *******/

pid_t varFork, varFork2;

varFork = fork();

if(varFork == -1) //If we have an error, we close the process
{
    printf("ERROR\n");
    exit(-1);
}
else if (varFork == 0) //if we have a son, we display it's ID and it's father's
{
    printf("SON 1\n");
    printf(" ID = %d, Father's ID = %d\n", getpid(), getppid());

    varFork2 = fork();//creation of the second fork

    if(varFork2 == -1) //If we have an error, we close the process
    {
        printf("ERROR\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if (varFork2 == 0) //now we have the son of the first son, so the grandson of the father
    {
        printf("\nGRANDSON 1\n");
        printf(" ID = %d, Father's ID = %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
    }
    else sleep(0.1);/*we wait 0.1sec so that the father doesn't die before we can 
        display it's id (and before the son process gets adopted by a user process descending from the initial              process)*/  
}
else //in the other case, we have a father
{
    sleep(0.1);//again we put the father asleep to avoid adoption
}
return 0;
}
```

How can I create X generations of grandsons, X being a global variable (1son, 1 grandson, 1 great-grandson,  etc.) ?

Comment: OT: `sleep()` takes an integer. So due to implicit type-conversion `sleep(0.1)` results in `sleep(0)`

Comment: `printf("Error\n")` is almost always *wrong*.  And by "almost always", I mean always.  There is a reason the the unix convention starts processes with 3 open file descriptors, and you should get in the habit of using them all.  Error messages should be both meaningful and written to the proper stream.  `fprintf(stderr, "Error\n")`

Comment: As for making messages meaningful, `man perror`

Comment: Thank you, I'll do it this way from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I create X generations

Before forking, decrement `X` and continue forking inside the child until `X` is `0`.

Or inside the child decrement `X` and only continue forking if after decrementing it `X` still is greater `0`.

The code might look like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

void logmsg(const char *, int);

#define MAX_GENERATIONS (4)

int main(void)
{
  pid_t pid = 0;

  for (size_t g = 0; g < MAX_GENERATIONS; ++g)
  {
    logmsg("About to fork.", 0);

    switch (pid = fork())
    {
      case -1:
      {
        logmsg("fork() failed", errno);

        break;
      }

      case 0:
      {
        logmsg("Hello world. I am the new child.", 0);

        break;
      }

      default:
      {
        char s[1024];
        snprintf(s, sizeof s, "Successfully created child carrying PID %d.", (int) pid);
        logmsg(s, 0);
        g = MAX_GENERATIONS; /* Child forked, so we are done, set g to end looping. */

        break;
      }
    }
  }

  logmsg("Sleeping for 3s.", 0);
  sleep(3);

  if (0 != pid) /* In case we forked a child ... */
  {
    logmsg("Waiting for child to end.", 0);
    if (-1 == wait(NULL)) /* ... wait for the child to terminate. */
    {
      logmsg("wait() failed", errno);
    }
  }

  logmsg("Child ended, terminating as well.", 0);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void logmsg(const char * msg, int error)
{
  char s[1024];
  snprintf(s, sizeof s, "PID %d: %s", (int) getpid(), msg);
  if (error)
  {
    errno = error;
    perror(s);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  puts(s);
}
```

The output should look similar to this:

```
PID 4887: About to fork.
PID 4887: Successfully created child carrying PID 4888.
PID 4887: Sleeping for 3s.
PID 4888: Hello world. I am the new child.
PID 4888: About to fork.
PID 4888: Successfully created child carrying PID 4889.
PID 4888: Sleeping for 3s.
PID 4889: Hello world. I am the new child.
PID 4889: About to fork.
PID 4889: Successfully created child carrying PID 4890.
PID 4890: Hello world. I am the new child.
PID 4890: About to fork.
PID 4889: Sleeping for 3s.
PID 4890: Successfully created child carrying PID 4891.
PID 4890: Sleeping for 3s.
PID 4891: Hello world. I am the new child.
PID 4891: Sleeping for 3s.
PID 4888: Waiting for child to end.
PID 4890: Waiting for child to end.
PID 4891: Child ended, terminating as well.
PID 4890: Child ended, terminating as well.
PID 4887: Waiting for child to end.
PID 4889: Waiting for child to end.
PID 4889: Child ended, terminating as well.
PID 4888: Child ended, terminating as well.
PID 4887: Child ended, terminating as well.
```

The difference with my code above compared to the proposal I made is that it counts upwards to `X`.

Comment: I don't get it. Won't this just create brothers? Because if we continue forking inside the child, it will have X-1 grandsons but all the grandsons will be brothers and not great-grandsons, great-great-grandsons etc.

Comment: @Unck: If you let each child(-process) do only exactly one fork, then each generation will have exactly one child.

Comment: Alright but as I create a loop with X repetitions, how can one child do one fork ? Shall I have 2 fork? One for the child process and one for the grandchild? And repeat this loop with the grandchild become the father of a new child at every repetitions?

Comment: You might like to have a look at my updated answer ... ;-)

Comment: Ah ok ! Creating a switch in the loop to get the son was a smart idea. Now I get it. I really did not think about giving back the MAX_GENERATION value to the loop variable inside the loop. Thank you very much for your help sir

Comment: @Unck: "*giving back the MAX_GENERATION*" this is just *one* possibility to break the for-loop. One also could use a dedicated break-flag. And test for this either explicitly at the bottom of the loop, or inside the for-loop's break condition. But why not reuse what's already around? ;-)

Comment: You are absolutely right. I'm just a beginner so I still have much to learn :-)

Comment: @Unck: BTW, if you feel this answers your question, you are free to mark this answer as such by clicking it's check-mark.

Comment: May I ask you something else? What program do you use in Linux to code? Because on Windows I'm using Visual Studio and I was not able to find a similar program. In linux i use Gedit but it's just a text editor with no real features.